# Problems with understanding KeyEvent in Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a program where three buttons are entered, and each time something different happens for them.

I know that I have to use `keyPressed`, but it's really confusing me because when I run my program, it doesn't wait for me to enter anything.

I've just been following online guides since I'm pretty new to programming in general, so if you have a better way of doing it all together then please do say so.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Trial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Medical Registration Form program.");
    System.out.println("To enter a new patient's details, press 'N'");
    System.out.println("To access an existing pateient's details, press 'S'");
    System.out.println("To see all patient deatils currently saved, press 'P'");
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
      System.out.println("You pressed a valid button");  
    } else {
      System.out.println("You pressed a bad button!");
      e.consume();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't added a `KeyListener`, or a Frame to catch any key events.

Comment: Which magic should fire that event and call your handler? You need to create an UI control and add listener for your key event of it. If you don't need UI (you're doing console application) you can use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm making a console application. But cheers, I'll look at the scanner and keylistener.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the console, follow this snippet code:

```
public class Demo{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Medical Registration Form program.");
    System.out.println("To enter a new patient's details, press 'N'");
    System.out.println("To access an existing pateient's details, press 'S'");
    System.out.println("To see all patient deatils currently saved, press 'P'");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.next();

    if(input.matches("S")){
        System.out.println("You pressed a valid button");  
    } else {
        System.out.println("You pressed a bad button!");

    }
}
```

Otherwise, extend from Jframe and implements KeyListener as follows:

```
public class Demo extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

public Demo(){

    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Medical Registration Form program.");
    System.out.println("To enter a new patient's details, press 'N'");
    System.out.println("To access an existing pateient's details, press 'S'");
    System.out.println("To see all patient deatils currently saved, press 'P'");
    Demo demo = new Demo();
}   

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        System.out.println("You pressed a valid button");  
    } else {
        System.out.println("You pressed a bad button!");
        e.consume();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Minor quibble; class `Demo` doesn't call any JFrame methods, like it's constructor or setting the size.

Comment: @SteveSmith methods will be invoked whenever a key event happens, and yes setSize and setVisible(true).

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @Pillow123 your welcome. If it solved your problem check it as the answer.